# Rails 3 after_save old value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do you work with the old values of a record being updated?

For instance in the following code block how would I run a query using the previous winner_id field after I determine that it has indeed changed?

```
if self.winner_id_changed?
   old_value = self.changed_attributes
   User.find(old_value)
   #do stuff with the old winner....
end
```

An example output of `self.changed_attributes` would be:

> {"winner_id"=>6}

Do I really have to convert this to a string and parse out the value in order to perform a query on it? `old_value[:winner_id]` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use where instead of find, and the following inject method on changes to generate the desired hash:

```
if self.winner_id_changed?
   old_value = self.changes.inject({}) { |h, (k,v)| h[k] = v.first }
   old_user = User.where(old_value)
   #do stuff with the old user....
end
```

You can also use ActiveRecord dirty methods such as:

```
self.winner_id_was
```

to get specific attribute's old value. Full documentation may be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Comment: Thanks, the dirty method seemed to be what I was looking for. Also in hindsight I realized that I could have simply done `old_value["winner_id"]` because `changed_attributes` returns a hash of **strings** and not symbols which I'm so used to using.